# PhP if statement using GET

Tags: php, html, forms, get

Ive created a dropdown list which passes its value using GET to a php value. if i just echo this value then it changes every time the dropdown is changed, however when i try use this value in an if statement it always uses the echo option given from the top value

```
<form action="" align="center" method ="get">
<select name="mylist" onChange="this.form.submit()">
<option>Filter By Team</option>
<option value="1">All Players</option>
<option value="2">Micros</option>
<option value="3">U7s</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php
$team = $_GET["mylist"];
if ($team="1") {
  echo "Filtering for All Players";
} elseif ($team="2") {
  echo "Filtering for 2";
} else {
  echo "Filtering for 3";
}
```

is the code i am using

thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are presently assigning using a single `=` sign, instead of comparing using  2x `==` signs.

```
if ($team==1) {
  echo "Filtering for All Players";
} elseif ($team==2) {
  echo "Filtering for 2";
} else {
  echo "Filtering for 3";
}
```

For more information on assignment operators, visit PHP.net

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

and on  comparison operators

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Do tick the checkmark so the question can be closed properly. @user1864310